# Angular 2 way Binding for a component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-directive, ngfor

I am creating a simple to-do application in angular. I just want to know is there any way to Bind in a 2 way when using ngFor directive

Is there any way to get the data "each-component" and remove from the list present in the "app-component"

i am using  [(size)]="x" for 2 way binding

app.component.html

```
<input type="button" value="add"  (click)="foo()">
<hr>
<app-each *ngFor="let x of ltodod" [(size)]="x"></app-each>
```

app.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('todo') val:ElementRef;
  title = 'todo';
  t=""
  ltodod=[]
  foo()
  {
      this.ltodod.push(this.val.nativeElement.value);
      console.log(this.ltodod);
  }
  foo1(e)
  {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```

each.component.html

```
  <h1>task:{{size}}</h1>
  <button (click)="foo()" >remove</button>
</div>
```

each.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit,Input, Output,EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-each',
  templateUrl: './each.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./each.component.css']
})
export   class EachComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() sizeChange=new EventEmitter();
@Input() size;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  foo()
  {
    this.sizeChange.emit("fsdfd");
    console.log("emited")
  }

}
```

Comment: a very good blog post about 2 way binding: https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/13/two-way-data-binding-in-angular-2.html

Comment: what is the problem here? is anything working not as you expected?

Answer (score 0):

> **You cannot assign $event to the template variables because it is
> read-only and created only for the template level scope.**

In the below statement ( your scenario ) you have created the **variable x with let keyword** and it is only available in the template within only the *ngFor scope. But this x type of variable is not present in the `<app-each>`. Hence it will not work.

<app-each ***ngFor="let x of ltodod" [(size)]="x"** >        //Will not work